# Что делать, когда просят ссылки, а потом получают ссылки?

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок

[Нередко бывает в очереди проверок «Сообщения низкого качества»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/38616), что есть ответ, который в принципе содержит только ссылки, на [вопрос, который в принципе просит такие ссылки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/261261/websocket-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Обычно, когда я вижу ответы только с одними ссылками, рекомендую удаление под такой причиной:

> **Этот ответ-ссылка (а не спам)**
>   “Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.”

Но в данном случае такой комментарий вряд ли поможет: на вопрос типа «посоветуйте библиотеки», нечего сказать, кроме «вот вам библиотеки, они очень клёвые».

В любом случае, вопрос должен быть закрыт. А что нам делать с этими ответами в проверке?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Отвечать "Выглядит нормально".

Во-первых, ответ вполне соответствует вопросу. Если удалят вопрос, то удаление ответов уже не будет иметь значения - нельзя удалить одно и то же дважды. Если не удалят, то ответ дан именно такой, какой хотели.

Во-вторых, в ответе с библиотеками само название библиотеки является сутью. Если даже ссылка утратит актуальность, название библиотеки всё равно останется и её можно будет найти по этому названию (если она того заслуживает, естественно).

Comment: Тут есть небольшая проблема: нужно заглядывать и в вопрос. Если я не ошибаюсь, в стандартной форме вопрос [полу]скрыт.

Comment: @VladD, насколько я помню, вопрос там прочитать можно...

Comment: Угу, но это неочевидно. Обычно проверяющий действует по алгоритму «одна ссылка => жмём „ответ-ссылка”» (и не читает Мету).

Comment: @VladD, а открыть и проверить на спам?

Comment: Согласен. Тогда пройти по ссылке, если спам, пометить как спам, иначе как ответ-ссылка.