# Что делать с вопросами про поиск библиотек/плагинов/инструментов/приложений

Tags: обсуждение, тематика, закрытие-вопросов

Последнее время все чаще на глаза попадаются вопросы про поиск библиотек, плагинов, инструментов, ПО и прочего. Примеры таких вопросов:

- [Плагин для вывода ярлычков (наклеек) на миниатюры товаров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496231/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8E%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2)
- [Подскажите класс для записи ini](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496701/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-ini)
- [Автоматический секундомер при заходе на любой сайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496872/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82)

На en.SO такие вопросы считаются офтопиком, так как ответы слишком уж подвержены личному мнению. Кроме того, ответы на такие вопросы чаще всего являются ответами-ссылками. Да, такие [ответы допускаются сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1638/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8), все же не вписываются в концепцию ru.SO. А еще, такие ответы достаточно быстро устаревают.

Какова позиция сообщества ru.SO по этому вопросу? Нужно ли закрывать/минусовать/удалять подобные вопросы?

---

**Замечание:**

Речь не идет о вопросах о поиске литературы, так как текущая позиция сообщества [уже выражена вот в этом ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C/162#162).

**UPD:**

[Справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) говорит, что такие вопросы лучше не задавать:

> Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию. Для списков литературы выделены особые поддерживаемые сообществом вопросы.

Comment: Во-первых, справку можно менять, во-вторых, "где найти" я понимаю как "где скачать", а не "как называется".

Answer (score 12):

Вопросы по поиску библиотек вполне вписываются в стандартные критерии оценки.
Если точно изложена проблема и определены требования - всё замечательно.
Если вопрос задан кое-как а мне тут что-то надо, помогите - то закрывать.

Закрывать все вопросы про библиотеки нельзя. Программирование во многом строится на поиске и переиспользовании существующего кода - мы не можем говорить спрашивающему: "Не, мы библиотеки не ищем, катись отсюда, а как какую-нибудь хрень прикрутишь, возвращайся с десятком вопросов по ней".

Про приложения и инструменты - то же самое.

---

> @Qwertiy, это я специально для тебя привел пример типового вопроса о поиске библиотеки. Если ты хочешь конкретики, пожалуйста, в теле вопроса если ссылка на вопрос о поиске плагина для WP. Как ты считаешь, заслуживает ли он жизни или нет?

#### [Плагин для вывода ярлычков (наклеек) на миниатюры товаров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496231)

Я не php-разработчик, wordpress не видел и не использовал, так что редкость и конкретность того, о чём он спрашивает, оценить не могу. Хотя, кажется, что область ограничена очень конкретно тегами [wordpress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) и [woocommerce](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce). Ограничение области - это плюс для вопроса.

В общем, я не вижу в нём ничего плохого. Я бы не трогал такой вопрос до появления ответов. На него реально дать хороший ответ.

Кроме того, у этого вопроса нулевое количество голосов и всего 12 просмотров, несмотря на то, что на него ссылка на мете. Значит, с большой долей вероятности, область, о которой он спрашивает непопулярна, поэтому могу предположить, что нагуглить хороший ответ самостоятельно может быть проблематично. Это тоже за этот вопрос.

Итог: вопрос заслуживает право на жизнь. По крайней мере, на данный момент. Кстати, если он останется с нулевым рейтингом и без ответов, то его всё равно дух соберёт, так что нет никакого смысла проявлять по отношению к нему излишнюю активность. Если кто-то знает - пусть ответит, а там видно будет.

#### [Подскажите класс для записи ini](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496701)

Нормальный вопрос. Весьма распространённая задача, а в большинстве языков встроенных средств нет. Функции winapi имеют очень низкую производительность из-за того, что для каждого параметра заново читают файл.

#### https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496887

Похоже на программирование методом копипаста шмотков кода из разных источников по принципу "авось взлетит". Чётких требований нет, описания, где его собираются использовать, тоже. Плохой вопрос.

#### [Автоматический секундомер при заходе на любой сайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496872)

Нормальный вопрос. Было бы неплохо уточнить браузер. И ответить на вопрос из комментария. Впрочем, на качество самого вопроса не влияет.

Comment: А вас не смущает, что рекомендации по использованию библиотек слишком уж субъективны? А меня смущает.

Comment: Чем конкретнее критерии в вопросе, тем объективнее рекомендации.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, а своему собственному мнению и опыту Вы тоже не доверяете?

Comment: @avp, по-моему, ru.SO это про конкретные вопросы и ответы, а не про мнения.

Comment: @Qwertiy, критерии отбора библиотеки - это очень тонкая вещь. Если их мало -- вопрос не конкретен, если много -- проблема XY. Попасть "в точку", в общем случае очень-очень сложно

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, в любом вопросе так. По сути, то же требование минимального примера, только в несколько изменённом виде.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ок, а как человек, не имеющий представлений о том что могут современные библиотеки в незнакомом языке программирования может составить минимальный пример?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, в незнакомом языке? о_О Т. е. не зная язык, ты начинаешь искать библиотеки? А как человек, имеющий шмоток кода на незнакомом языке, сделает из него минимальный пример для вопроса?

Comment: @Qwertiy, это я специально для _тебя_ привел пример типового вопроса о поиске библиотеки. Если _ты_ хочешь конкретики, пожалуйста, в теле вопроса есть ссылка на вопрос о поиске плагина для WP. Как _ты_ считаешь, заслуживает ли он жизни или нет?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, ответ дополнен.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, ответ дополнен.

Comment: Поиск плагинов - это как-то не совсем программирование. Точно так же, как сходить в чебуречную != кулинария.

Comment: Любопытно, получается в этом вопросе ru.SO расходится с оригиналом. По привычке после en.SO хотел поставить флаг на вопросе про поиск компонентов и с удивлением не нашел причины "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @icebat, это далеко не единственный пункт, где правила расходятся :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, отличий я заметил немало. Нередко встечаются плюсовые вопросы, которые были бы жестко заминусованы на en.SO. С одной стороны, это может быть хорошо, учитывая что контента тут гораздо меньше и есть специфика. Но с другой возникает мысль, что ru.SO не берет все лучшие практики, к которым en.SO пришел за годы развития.

Comment: @icebat, просто сайтов на английском много, а на русском - только один.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, но SO крупнейший сайт вопросов-ответов для программистов. Он, по большому счету, тоже только один на верхушке. И ru.SO видится как его ответвление. Я не хочу спорить и не считаю, что ru.SO совершает какие-то грубые ошибки, просто функционал и практики на en.SO не на ровном месте появились. Но если система без проблем работает и по своей вариации правил, что ж, в этом нет ничего плохого.

Comment: @icebat, а как же serverfault и superuser?

Comment: @Qwertiy, эти сайты не имеют отношения к изначальному вопросу. Количество тем на ru.SO может быть шире, но это не влияет на вопросы, которые подпадают под указанную выше причину. Более того, в правилах даже пункт, что не стоит задавать "вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию". Почему нет под этого флага, не совсем понятно.

Comment: @icebat, неужели только я понимаю фразу "где найти" как "с какого сайта скачать"?

Comment: @Qwertiy, в контексте SO это схожие вопросы и оба не по теме. Ответ на SO должен автономным, чтобы если ссылка умерла, ответ не развалился. По этой причине на SO удаляются link-only answers. Рекомендации, в дополнение к этому, нередко субъективны. Все это более подробно расписано в правилах, причем даже тут, на ru.SO - так что это не мое личное мнение, и не совсем понятно, что мы, в общем-то, сейчас обсуждаем =)

Answer (score 6):

На основном SO есть специальный флаг для этого:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it

В [справке по вопросам на ru.SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) есть пункт о том, что не стоит задавать

> вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию.

А также в [правилах по ответам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) сказано, что ответы-ссылки будут удаляться.
В итоге, мы получаем то же, что и на SO - рекомендательные вопросы-ответы не приветствуются.

Более того, два из трех указанных вопросов уже закрыты по этой причине. Почему бы тогда просто не ввести соответсвующий флаг, как на SO?

Comment: Во-первых, указано было 4 вопроса. Во-вторых, 2 из них вполне можно закрыть по другим причинам. А в одном я уже проголосовал за переоткрытие. Далее, "где найти" я понимаю как "откуда скачать". Хорошую программу и библиотеку вполне можно найти по её названию даже если её официальный сайт больше не существует, поэтому в данном случае ответы-ссылки [разрешены](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1639/178988), т. к. ссылка в них не является первичной информацией.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я понимаю ваше субъективное мнение по этому вопросу. Оно расходится с политикой SO. В приведенном вами примере вопрос был удален.

Comment: Пример не мой. Все примеры взяты из вопроса, просто потом вопрос был отредактирован.

Comment: В сети [есть](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/199411/309650) сайт, на котором подобные вопросы задавать можно. Зачем нам брать именно правила SO?

Comment: @Qwertiy, но мы вроде как "**SO** на русском", что создает некоторые ожидания соответствия.

Answer (score 5):

Конечно, оставлять.

Пусть те, у кого есть опыт в данной области, поделятся  своим мнением по поводу этих библиотек, плагинов, инструментов, ПО и прочего.

Некачественные вопросы и особенно ответы (само собой, при наличии собственного опыта использования такого ПО), естественно, надо минусовать.

Т.е. все как обычно.

Comment: Т.е. вы считаете, что вопросы по поиску библиотек - это обычные вопросы, в то время как вопросы о поиске литературы -- [существенно ограничены](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)? Как-то это совсем уже не логично...

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, я бы и вопросы по поиску литературы не слишком ограничивал. Но в этой области все же проще сделать несколько канонических ответов и (безболезненно?) отсылать к ним, а вот с ПО такого не получится. Проще отвечать на каждый вопрос с учетом его специфики (и вероятно переговоров с ТС в комментариях).

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, библиотеки ищутся под конкретную задачу, а литература - нет.

Comment: Поиск библиотеки под конкретную задачу попахивает проблемой XY. И это в лучшем случае. В худшем, вопрос сводится к "_мне бы библиотеку, которая все за меня делает_" (без какой бы то ни было конкретики о проблеме).

Answer (score 4):

Однозначно оставлять, иначе непонятно, зачем вообще, в своё время, ХешКод переехал под крылышко SE. Чтобы спрашивать ни о чём было нельзя?

Маленькая отсылка к истории: в Сети Знаний (место, из которого вырос ruSO) было три айтишных ресурса: ХешКод(вопросы программистов), БитКод(вопросы пользователей) и РутКод(вопросы администраторов). Вопросы по поиску софта зачастую переправлялись с ХешКода на Рут или БитКод, как не соответствующие тематике, так же, как и на enSO. Однако, из ресурсов Сети Знаний лишь ХешКод и Русский Язык пользовались достаточной популярностью. В результате, ХешКод, БитКод и РутКод были **слиты** в один сайт ruSO, при переезде, **а на старых адресах этих сайтов висит заглушка, предлагающая задать свой вопрос на ruSO**, что, фактически, делает вопросы со всех трёх этих ресурсов соответствующими тематике ruSO.

В SE действительно есть [сайт](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) для рекомендаций софта, более того, там есть куча специализированных ресурсов (например, [вопросы по графическому дизайну](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)), где подобные вопросы вряд ли будут восприняты в штыки, если ищется **тематический** софт. **Однако**, все эти сайты **предназначены для англоязычного сегмента пользователей**, поэтому туда нельзя перенаправить вопрос на русском языке. Отсюда и разница в критериях соответствия тематике на ruSO и enSO. Добейтесь создания русских версий этих сайтов, приведите туда людей, - и тогда уже будет смысл менять правила ruSO, не раньше.

Comment: *что, фактически, делает вопросы со всех трёх этих ресурсов соответствующими тематике ruSO* - нет, это додумывание. Руткод вошел в онтопик, Биткод - нет. Русскоязычные версии прочих сайтов  совершенно точно не появятся в обозримой перспективе.

Comment: @Nofate тогда зачем пользователей БитКода отправляют сюда, если их вопросы здесь - оффтопик? Только сегодня смотрел: На Биткоде висит такая же заглушка, как и на ХК.

Comment: Это довольно разумно с исторической точки зрения. Но пользователи, пришедшие с en.SO, воспринимают ru.SO как русский аналог с теми же правилами (во всяком случае по себе могу сказать). Да правила и есть те же, судя по Справке.
Возникает двойственность. Нужно либо пользователям старых ресурсов привыкнуть к практикам SO, либо изменить правила, приняв историческую и региональную специфику как более важный аспект.

Comment: @icebat беда в том, что сказать человеку, пришедшему по заглушке с БитКода "теперь ты свои вопросы задавать можешь только по-английски, вон на том сайте, привыкай", довольно странно. А так и придётся сделать, если брать за истину стандарты enSO.

Comment: _слиты в один сайт ruSO, при переезде._ – Не совсем так. Мы объединили сообщества системных администраторов и программистов где–то за год до перехода на новую платформу. БитКод не становился часть ХэшКода и Stack Overflow на русском.

Comment: А для чего еще? Есть mail.ru, где можно задавать любые вопросы или форумы

Comment: Что за глупые названия сайтов? при чем тут биты и код, если вопросы про windows?

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю закрывать подобные вопросы с формулировкой

> необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ

Вместе с тем, нужно указывать автору вопроса в комментариях, что вместо запроса на поиск библиотеки/плагина/ПО правильнее было бы описать конкретную проблему. Это поможет решить сразу несколько проблем:

- Будет меньше вопросов с [проблемой X-Y](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy).
- Вопрос не будет притягивать малополезные, субъективно окрашенные ответы-ссылки.
- Не нужно будет толерантно относится к ответам ссылкам, поскольку вопрос будет о конкретной проблеме, а не о поиске чего бы то ни было.

Comment: А вот представьте. Вы решили написать программу на новом для себя языке и хотите *быстро* узнать, чем удобнее прочесть, ну сажем, CSV файл. А вам в ответ -- "это неформат, ищите в гугле" (хотя, посылать туда уже не рекомендуется, но кто-нибудь обязательно пошлет). Приятная ситуация?

Comment: @avp, лично я с гугла бы и начал, так как искренне верю, что ru.SO это про **конкретные** вопросы, а не про любимые, субъективно хорошие библиотеки.

Comment: ОК. Нагуглили 5 штук. Все самому исследовать? Проще сначала спросить мнение тех, кто уже наступал на эти грабли и тут уже решать, чьему мнению Вы доверяете. А чем  д.б. ruSO позвольте каждому решать самому.

Comment: @avp, ключевое слово в вашем комментарии "_мнение_". Если ru.SO претендует на звание "базы знаний", то субъективные мнения не должны составлять основу контента.

Comment: В том то и дело. В идеале как раз наоборот. Именно субъективные мнения   участников (достигших нужного уровня) должны становиться знаниями, наполняющими эту базу. Понятно, что к этому идти и идти (прежде всего привлекая, а не отталкивая всякими странными ограничениями и попытками всех построить,  таких людей).

Comment: На SO уже есть флаг "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it". 
В правилах ru.SO есть пункт, что что не стоит задавать "вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию". Лучше тоже добавить флаг для этого, тогда уж.

Comment: @icebat, добавьте свой ответ и посмотрим, как сообщество на него отреагирует.