# Тематичен ли поиск VPN?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов, тематика

Насколько тематичен для сайта вопрос типа:

- [VPN. Нужен бесплатный и хороший vpn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1069408/213987)

Это не принципы выбора хорошего VPN, в то время как просят именно "рыбу, но не удочку" -- и ответы превращаются в список ссылок, которые со временем будут протухать.

С другой стороны, непонятно, стоит ли применить пункт [правил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать:
>
> Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по
>   программированию и администрированию.

Comment: Не считая того, что сам вопрос плохо сформулирован и задан (и за это получил часть минусов), имхо все же оффтопик.

Comment: Довольно жизненный вопрос. Исходя из правил, конечно оффтопик, но несмотря на это, было бы прекрасно собрать подобные ссылки, как мы, например, делаем с учебными ресурсами. Одного FAQ-вопроса было бы достаточно. Лично мне, как разработчику, это было бы полезно.

Answer (score 7):

Квертий в своё время [расписал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2619/15479) это в контекст поиска библиотек. Думаю, тут то же самое.

> Если точно изложена проблема и определены требования - всё замечательно.

Но в случае с либами, всё же, их ищут для использовании при написании кода.

В случае же с VPN, предпосылки у вопроса могут быть разные. Я бы так разделил:

- Как настроить VPN у себя на сервере? - ОК.
- Как добавить в своё приложение использование vpn/прокси? - ОК.
- Как написать свой VPN? - ОК.
- Где найти VPN для обхода блокировок? - Не ОК.

Т.е, если VPN нужен как инструмент для решения более общей проблемы при разработке - оставлять. Если ищут VPN просто для того, чтоб использовать его в повседневных целях - закрывать.

Comment: Ну а где же тогда попросить их url-ы, как не у товарищей по сайту?

Comment: @avp забанют наш любимый ruSO за такие просьбы (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Неужели нельзя публиковать ссылки на подобные ресурсы?

Comment: @nomnoms12 конечно можно. Но Роскомнадзор не дремлет)

Comment: Значит их надо кодировать (шарады загадывать) -)

Answer (score 3):

Этот конкретный вопрос - скорее всего оффтопик, но лично мне его закрывать жалко, потому что он мне в целом кажется полезным. Есть подозрение, что я не один так считаю, раз голосов за закрытие на данный момент всего 2.

Что касается тревоги на ответе со ссылкой, я её отклонил в соответствии с [этим обсуждением](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1639/178988). Я не представляю, какую информацию можно было бы перенести из ссылки в ответ. Ну максимум - характеристики и ограничения, но вероятность что они поменяются больше, чем вероятность протухания ссылки. Да и если в вопросе просят найти внешний сервис, то если этот сервис закроется, то никакая перенесённая в ответ информация никак никому не поможет. Так что ответ полностью отвечает на вопрос и применять к нему какие-то санкции причин нет.